# Can I deduce the max. shutter speed from other camera specs?

Tags: canon, shutter-speed, specification

I have the following specs for a Canon Rebel T3 EOS dSLR:

12.2 Megapixel CMOS (APS-C) sensor and DIGIC 4 Image Processor for high image quality and speed

ISO 100-6400 for shooting from bright to dim light

[ ... Clearly irrelevant long section removed to keep the question open ...]

From this, is there any way to 'deduce' the max shutter speed or do I have to call up the retailer and ask?

Comment: from [the canon website](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_rebel_t3_18_55mm_is_ii_lens_kit#Specifications) it appears to be 1/4000 second

Comment: And the other question I always ask at this point: why is it important to you what the max shutter speed is?

Comment: for fast action photography, like bird flying

Comment: For which the answer is "any camera will have a fast enough shutter" - it's other things you need to worry about, like the AF system.

Comment: Maybe the bird has rocket boosters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to deduce the max shutter speed. It's typically listed in the same specs where you'd find the kind of information you've listed, in fact.

Comment: Yes, it is hardly amongst the manufacturer's secrets.

Answer (score 0):

You can nearly deduce the physical max. shutter speed from the x-sync time of the camera. 
But for most cases in which the shutter speed is really relevant, this information is not relevant. Practially most bodies achieve much shorter exposure times (not shutter speeds to be accurate) by releasing the 2nd curtain of the shutter well before the 1st has exposed the film/sensor totally. By doing so some thin stripe of light will expose the film/sensor.

So when the shutter speed is 1/250 s and the stripe betwenn 1st and 2nd shutter curtain is only 1/16th of the film/sensor height, the effective exposure time is effectively 1/4000 s.

As for your question, you cannot deduce neither, max shutter speed nor min exposure time from the numbers given in your question.

Comment: I think you're getting a little too pedantic between shutter speed and minimum exposure time. While it may be wrong, and makes the physicist in me very angry :-), "shutter speed" has a well defined meaning in the photography world, even if it's not a speed in any way.

Comment: There is also the 'electronic shutter' done by opening the shutter fully and then turning on and off the sensor for the requisite time... Which can be almost anything.